# Discord Js : I am trying to make a code that if the user has a certain word in there username then give them a certain role?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So say if my username is [Agent] Dynamic1619. I want to check if the user has the '[Agent]' part in their name and give them a specific role. I am new to JS and Discord bot making. Please help. :)

So this is the code

```
const cmdrole = "your role's name";
const cmdtag = "your tag, like [Advast]";

bot.on("message", message =>{
    if(message.content.includes(" ")) {
        let membersforrole = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.nickname.includes(cmdtag));
        if(!message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name = "cmdrole")) return message.reply("Role not found.");
        membersforrole.roles.add(cmdrole);
    };
});
```

But it says it could not read ^ .includes

Answer (score 0):

I have checked that there is NO way of doing it without relying on something simple. Eg : My way requires your server to have somebody typing " " in their message, else wise, you can also type it.

```js
const cmdrole = "your role's name";
const cmdtag = "your tag, like [Advast]";

bot.on("message", message =>{
    if(message.content.includes(" ")) {
        let membersforrole = message.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.nickname.includes(cmdtag));
        if(!message.guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name = "cmdrole")) return message.reply("Role not found.");
        membersforrole.roles.add(cmdrole);
    };
});
```

Hope this helps, Also, if it doesn't work, you can change the spacebar to something else widely spoken in your server.

Comment: BTW it says that could not read .includes ??  what do I do?? @FanBoy9344